# Minimum value of $\frac{4}{x}+2x+10+\frac{3+x}{4x^2+1}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, supremum-and-infimum

If the minimum value of $\frac{4}{x}+2x+10+\frac{3+x}{4x^2+1}$ when $x>0$ is $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in N$ then find the least value of $(p+q).$

I can find the minimum value of $\frac{4}{x}+2x$ using $AM- GM$ inequality but that too comes irrational and when i tried to find the minimum value of $\frac{3+x}{4x^2+1}$ using first derivative test,i am facing difficulty.Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in light of Marthkencombo's answer I suspect that the problem may have been transcribed incorrectly. May be the question is simply to minimize $p+q$ among the rational values attained by the function at some point $x>0$? In other words, we are not at all interested in finding the exact minimum of that horrid rational function. Just needing to check whether it attains $1/1$, $1/2$, $2/1$, $\ldots$. Hmm.... the function is unbounded, so that seems to lead to finding the smallest positive integer in its range, so may be I'm wrong.

Comment: May be we are simply to restrict ourselves to rational inputs $x$, and then minimize $p+q$ within the range? That would, at least at the first glance, make an interesting question!

Answer (score 4):

While the answers that have been proposed already are great, I think that rather than trying to find the positive roots of the following polynomial :

\begin{align}
32x^6-52x^4-24x^3-29x^2-4&=0,
\end{align}

your problem could be solved more easily by using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

> **Rational root theorem :**
>   Let $P(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ where every $a_k$ is an integer and $a_n\neq0$. If $\alpha$ is a rational root of $P(x)$, then $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}$ where :
>
> - $p$ divides $a_0$,
> - $q$ divides $a_n$,
> - $\gcd(p,q)=\pm1$.

In your case, you are looking for a positive rational root hence we can narrow the possible values to $4$, $2$, $1$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{1}{16}$, $\frac{1}{32}$.

As none of these values is a root of our polynomial, you can conclude that the minimum of your function is not reached at a positive rational.

Answer (score -1):

HINT: There is another approach using calculus

let $$y=\frac{4}{x}+2x+10+\frac{3+x}{4x^2+1}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4}{x^2}+2+\frac{(4x^2+1)(1)-(3+x)(8x)}{(4x^2+1)^2}$$
Now, for maxima or minima, put $$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{(4x^2+1)(1)-(3+x)(8x)}{(4x^2+1)^2}-\frac{4}{x^2}+2=0$$
Since, $x>0$ then find the positive roots of the equation for minima & proceed